# Dropdown form Javascript create a range of numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a range of numbers in a dropdown form using JavaScript.

However, it looks like

[image]

…and it does not show any options and clicking on the arrow does not pop up more options. I already checked that my path is correct.

I tried it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x4Jh/106/) and it works but not when I put it in my HTML.

I'm going crazy on why this is not working.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/main.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="gradient">
    <div id="down" class="center">
        <p >Word Size</p>

        <select id="length">

        </select>          

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

main.js

```
var select = document.getElementById('length');    

for (var i = 0; i<= 24; i++){

    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = i;
    option.innerHTML = i;
    select.options.add(option);
}
```

Comment: You've added the script before the HTML in the DOM, so the select element doesn't exist when you're trying to populate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when `main.js` script is parsed and executed, there is no element with id `length` yet in DOM. The simplest solution is to move your script to the very end of `body` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/main.css">
</head>

<body id="gradient">
    <div id="down" class="center">
        <p >Word Size</p>
        <select id="length"></select>          
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The reason why it works in jsFiddle, is because it's configured so that script section is executed on `window.onload` event (in the right side-panel, dropdown "onLoad"). Of course, you could do the same, e.g. in main.js:

```
window.onload = function() { /* previous main.js code */};
```

In this case you would not need to move script anywhere.